# How to solve Android P DownloadManager stopping with "Cleartext HTTP traffic to 127.0.0.1 not permitted"?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have already defined a custom network security config and included it in my manifest as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

**res/xml/network_security_config.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
  </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>
```

and this is in my **Android.manifest**:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:allowBackup="false"
             android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
             android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
             android:persistent="true" >
```

Even with these changes when attempting to communicate via HTTP to 127.0.0.1 I see this in logcat:

```
08-09 10:50:34.395 30791  3607 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
08-09 10:50:34.397 30791  3607 D NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
08-09 10:50:34.401 30791  3607 W DownloadManager: [647] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 127.0.0.1 not permitted
08-09 10:50:34.402 30791  3607 D DownloadManager: [647] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
```

**EDIT: Update (21 Aug 2018) after "fixing" this issue it seems that a couple of hours after the app is installed the DownloadManager mysteriously stops accepting cleartext HTTP.**

**I can't explain what's happening. If I reboot the device things work great for a period of time then DownloadManager refuses cleartext again. I'm writing this off as an Android P bug that I hope gets resolved.**

**EDIT 2: Update (17 Jan 2019) my pixel2 is now running android 9 with a patch from 5 Jan 2019 and I no longer see the issue (so far). I'm guessing this got resolved in some patch since August.**

Comment: add also <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/> in  <network-security-config> ... close it with </base-config>

Comment: @user3344236 replacing domain-config with base-config solved it! Submit your response as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Spartygw, in response to "EDIT: Update (21 Aug 2018)" I see the same thing as you. It works, then stops working after a few hours. To temporarily resolve the issue I can force quit the Download Manager app, restart my app and try the download again and it will work. I agree with you. It does seem like a bug in Android P's code in Download Manager.

Comment: @spartygw I've filed an issue to Google regarding your Update (21 Aug 2018). https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114143692

Comment: @LeonLu that's great! I wasn't even aware of how to raise this as an issue so I'm thankful that you did.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Create a XML res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Reference this file in your tag Application, inside AndroidManifest.xml. Like:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's right? shouldn't it either be a closing tag or />?

Comment: As you can already know the structure is XML and closing tag is  standardized as  </

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on closing tags! Now remove the trailing / from < base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" / > ;)

Comment: No need because is not a node John Smith  :)) the usual html closing is used also. Please read again the link.

Comment: After spending so many ways the clear text communication problem was resolved by using above code. Thank you very much.@user3344236

Comment: SOmehow it does not work for me, Any idea If there is something I need to add?

Comment: @Jalpesh For me too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3344236

Comment: If we set cleartextTrafficPermitted to true for base-config, aren't we defeating the purpose of network security policy? I  mean every HTTP will be accessed with this configuration.

Comment: How can we allow only our website for downloading files?

Comment: Not related to topic, but you can make rules with SSL pinning and allowed domains.

Answer (score 0):

Open manifest
[image]

Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
[image]