# Download Manager returns unsuccessful download on Android 9.0 NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Tags: android, networking, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

I am using Download Manager to download file from the internet. The download complete successfully in Android 6, 8.1, but not in Android 9.0

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDescription("Downloading...");
request.setTitle(nameOfFile);
request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/CPG", nameOfFile);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
queueId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: What is listed as the reason?

Comment: Provide more info on error. Some graphics would be more beneficial.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I have found the solution through here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770323/how-to-solve-android-p-downloadmanager-stopping-with-cleartext-http-traffic-to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution through here: [How to solve Android P DownloadManager stopping with "Cleartext HTTP traffic to 127.0.0.1 not permitted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770323/how-to-solve-android-p-downloadmanager-stopping-with-cleartext-http-traffic-to)

In short, I just need to do the following:

1.create res/xml/network_security_config.xml, then add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

2. in manifest file, reference it inside application tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

For more info, can read here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Comment: This does not work for people who are passing the http URL to download manager, will work for making other http calls in the same app. @Quicklearner were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Jalpesh look at this question of mine  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493077/download-manger-not-working-in-android-pie-9-0-xiaomi-mi-a2

Comment: Sorry, it Looks similar to the solution mentioned above, Am I missing anything?

Comment: This problem recur after sometime. I had to manually clear the cache for download manager to enable the downloading process again

Comment: This saved my day :)

Comment: @HuyMiracle, perhaps can try to programmatically clear the download manager cache

Answer (score 8):

This tag worked for me

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Add this tag to the application

```
 <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**Solution 2)**

Create a XML `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

in your tag Application inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

[Download Manger not working in Android Pie 9.0 (Xiaomi mi A2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493077/download-manger-not-working-in-android-pie-9-0-xiaomi-mi-a2)

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why the tag above works, and not the other one that I use?

Comment: i cant say because it might be device specific issue as well , i tried many solutions but none helped except this tag ..

Comment: Alright, If you found a general solution, let me know. :D

Comment: sure i will let u know

Comment: one more thing , when i cleared download manager cache , it started downloading the files again , thats strange though

Comment: I used that trick before, but the problem may recur. So you may need to do it again once in a while

Comment: I am gonna implement custom download manager for my requirement or use any library for that